# Getting name of child node which is holding another subchild

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
Child1
     Child1.1
              Subchild1
              Subchild 2
     Child 1.2
               Subchild 1
               Subchild 2
```

If I need to retrieve child1.1 and 1.2 how do I get them in textview?,  as their subchild can be retrieved easily using datasnapshot.

I dont have enogh reputation to post image so have to type the structure of my firebase project. Hope my problem is understandable.
Code What i done is...

```
LoggedInRef.child(number).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot != null) {
                    if (sampleList != null) {

                        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                  /*  msg_List_Item msgLIST=ds.getValue(msg_List_Item.class);

                        msgList.add(msgLIST);*/
                            Log.d("MESSAGES<<<<<<<<", ds.getValue().toString() + "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");
                            String msg = ds.getValue(String.class);              // problem is here............................................
                            String time = ds.child("DateTime").getValue(String.class);
                            String tag = ds.child("Tag").getValue(String.class);
                            msg_List_Item msg_list_item = new msg_List_Item(msg, time, tag);
                      /* msg_list_item.setMsg(msg);
                       msg_list_item.setDateTime(time);
                       msg_list_item.setTag(tag);*/

                            msgList.add(msg_list_item);


                            MessageAdapter = new msgAdapter(msgList, getApplicationContext());
                            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(MessageAdapter);
                            sampleList.clear();
                            mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(MessageAdapter.getItemCount());
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                        Toast.makeText(Message.this, "No data  found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
                    }}

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }}
        );
```

Comment: I think your data structure is sufficiently clear from the text. You should never need a picture for posting textual data. For example, you can get the JSON as text by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Aside from that, I'm not really sure what your trying to do, nor what you've already tried. You can navigate to a child node's snapshot with [`DataSnapshot.child("Subschild1")`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#child(java.lang.String)). If that is not what you're looking for or doesn't work, can you add the code of what you've already tried?

Comment: That is showing error... not right syntax.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question with the code in question. The behavior inside `onDataChange` now depends on what data exists at `LoggedInRef.child(number)`. Please edit your question to include that JSON (as plain text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Please add your database structure as JSON.

Comment: I actually re modify my structure and use push() to retrieve all values( as child node become subchild of push id and will be able to retrieve. ) and it worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
"1234567890" : {
    "-L7AhB1GWZPNqlte0tiX" : {
      "DateTime" : "09-03-2018 22:30",
      "MSG" : "hiii ",
      "Tag" : "ByMe"
    },
    "-L7AiOxVbSYAx8_0WqEa" : {
      "DateTime" : "09-03-2018 22:35",
      "MSG" : "how are you",
      "Tag" : "ByMe"
    },
    "-L7Ak1lhqn9EfD5YCOou" : {
      "DateTime" : "09-03-2018 22:42",
      "MSG" : "what are u doing?",
      "Tag" : "ByMe"
    },
    "-L7AkGekOzKzlLOwWNWp" : {
      "DateTime" : "09-03-2018 22:43",
      "MSG" : "I am fine",
      "Tag" : "NotByMe"
```

here is my Re modified structure!!!. ***Child node : *** **"DateTime", "MSG", "Tag"** become easier to fetch by using **push()**.